# How do I open Activity2 from Fragment1 button? Considering Fragment1 belongs to Activity1

Tags: java, android-studio

How do I open Activity2 from Fragment1 button? Considering Fragment1 belongs  to Activity1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your button's onClick methode :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Activity2.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```